# Get all match values from two comma separated string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

I have two comma separated string as follows,

```
var hiddenString = '14172,10062,14172,14172,100,10,14172,15000,12000';

var strB = '14172,10062,10064,10025,100,14182';
```

I need to create another string based on the above two,

if `hiddenString` have unmatching value with `strB`,then without those unmatched values need to create e new string and also avoid duplicates.
 simply says, I need to get all the matching values from both strings.

As the example based on my two string, I'm expecting the following:

```
varFinalHiddenString = 14172,10062,100;
```

How can I do this using JavaScript and that should work in *safari* and *IE 11* or its earlier versions. Please help me, I'm new to the JS.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this problem? show us your attempt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first `split()` strings to generate arrays from them. Then `filter()` the smaller array by checking the index of the current item with `indexOf()` in other array:

```js
var hiddenString = '14172,10062,14172,14172,100,10,14172,15000,12000';
var strB = '14172,10062,10064,10025,100,14182';
var temp1 = hiddenString.split(',');
var temp2 = strB.split(',');
var varFinalHiddenString = temp2.filter(function(s){
  return temp1.indexOf(s) > -1;
}).join(',');
console.log(varFinalHiddenString);
```

Comment: And I think arrow functions also not working with IE

Comment: @Mamum , Thank you sir, as sachith and Nick says, this is not working with IE, can you help me pls

Comment: @Adam, I have updated the answer, please check now:)

Comment: @Mamun in here is temp1 , temp2 are act as arrays? I;m correct?

Answer (score 0):

Make arrays of the strings, then use the "filter" method. Then convert back to string.

```
var hiddenString = '14172,10062,14172,14172,100,10,14172,15000,12000';
var strB = '14172,10062,10064,10025,100,14182';

var hiddenStringAsArray = hiddenString.split(',');
var strBArray = strB.split(',');

var resultObject = $(strBArray).filter(hiddenStringAsArray);
var resultArray = resultObject.toArray();
var resultString = resultArray.join(',');

console.log(resultString);
```